# How to keep the state of multiple <details> elements on page during a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page that contains multiple details elements and I was interested in persisting the state of each details element through localStorage/sessionStorage.  So if a user opens several of the details elements and then navigates to a new page and then back to the original page, the details elements that they originally opened would remain open.  Any help on the best way to do this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `id` to each detail element, and save in localStorage the state of it using the event `toggle`.

Then on page load, run on localStorage and add `open` to each detail

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/od8Lup9r/1/)

```js
(function() {
$('details').on('toggle', function(event) {
var id = $(this).attr('id')
var isOpen = $(this).attr('open')
console.log(id, isOpen)
window.localStorage.setItem('details-'+id, isOpen)
  })

function setDetailOpenStatus(item) {
  if (item.includes('details-')) {
var id = item.split('details-')[1];
var status = window.localStorage.getItem(item)
if (status == 'open'){
  $("#"+id).attr('open',true)
 }
   }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
setDetailOpenStatus(localStorage.key(i));
  }
});
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details id='1'>
      <summary>System Requirements 1</summary>
      <p>Requires a computer running an operating system. The computer
      must have some memory and ideally some kind of long-term storage.
      An input device as well as some form of output device is
      recommended.</p>
    </details>
    <details id='2'>
      <summary>System Requirements 2</summary>
      <p>Requires a computer running an operating system. The computer
      must have some memory and ideally some kind of long-term storage.
      An input device as well as some form of output device is
      recommended.</p>
    </details>
    <details id='3'>
      <summary>System Requirements 3</summary>
      <p>Requires a computer running an operating system. The computer
      must have some memory and ideally some kind of long-term storage.
      An input device as well as some form of output device is
      recommended.</p>
    </details>
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot!

Comment: Added JSFiddle example